# How can I send a request like in python and return the site response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Why my code in js dont sends the post data and in python works ?

In js

```
const options = {
    url: "https://asd.com",
    method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
            'User-Agent': 'my-reddit-client',
            'data': {"user.login":"login","user.senha":"pass"}
        }
    };

    request(options, function(err, resx, body) {        
        console.log(resx);
        res.send(body)
    });
```

In python

```
import requests
data = {
  "user.login":"login",
  "user.senha":"pass"
}
r = requests.post('https://asd.com', params=data)
print(r.text)
```

I just want to send a custom form without json format, but it never works.

Answer (score 1):

to make `POST` request in vanilla JS:

```
fetch("https://asd.com", {
  method: 'POST',
  body: {"user.login":"login","user.senha":"pass"},
  headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
   'User-Agent': 'my-reddit-client', 
  }
 }).then(res => res.json())
```

I suggest you also to read about the fetch API so It won't be hard for you anymore to make any other kind of request in JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch.

Comment: I've tried a bit, but the request type is not json... I just want to send a common request. but the data is not being send.